# C++ atexit handler for multithreading vs just letting the OS nuke it from orbit

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory-management

I have a main thread which has a console window. I use std::atexit() to register atexit_handler(). I then use SetConsoleCtrlHandler to regsiter a function whose entire purpose is to check if the DWORD it's passed equals CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT and if so call atexit_handler(). The main function has a while loop checking that global::exit is not true (global::exit being a boolean inside a namespace in main.h). When the while loop breaks the next step is to call atexit_handler() then return 0.

The problem is there's also a seperate thread, let's call it monitorThread, which could at any point declare that it's time to close, but if I have it do so by setting global::exit to true then that's one more thread (out of many not just these two) that has to interact with that shared variable. On the other hand I could have monitorThread call atexit_handler() and have atexit_handler() set exit to true before join()ing the other threads, but then main would end up calling atexit_handler() again.

So, my overall question is that since there's no data that needs to get flushed to disk, do I actually need to have exit handling functions to deallocate memory and join threads, or can I simply have monitorThread call exit() and let the OS nuke everything from orbit?

If I can simply have the OS deal with it then that simplifies things by letting me just get rid of the exit bool altogether.

Here's what I currently have:

GamewindowAndInput.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <Windows.h>
namespace GWAI {
    HWND getHWND();
    void inputLoop();
    void forkWaiter();
}
```

GamewindowAndInput.cpp:

```
#pragma once
#include "GamewindowAndInput.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "main.h"

HWND GWAI::getHWND() {
    HWND hwnd = FindWindow(NULL, L"[redacted]");
    if (hwnd == NULL) {
        "Game window not found, launching";
        //system("start [redacted]");
        //instead, fork exec ^, spawn new thread to wait on pid before setting exit to true
        Sleep(5000);
        hwnd = FindWindow(NULL, L"[redacted]");
    }
    while (hwnd == NULL) {
        std::cout << "Game window not found" << std::endl;
        Sleep(100);
        hwnd = FindWindow(NULL, L"[redacted]");
    }
    std::cout << "Valid HWND" << std::endl;
    return hwnd;
}
void GWAI::forkWaiter() {

}
void GWAI::inputLoop() {
    while (true) {
        //migrate from main.cpp
    }
}
```

main.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <Windows.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[]);
namespace global {
    bool run = false, exit = false; //replace with atomic bool?
    HWND hwnd;
}
BOOL WINAPI cntrlHandler(DWORD type);
void atexit_handler();
```

main.cpp:

```
#pragma once
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "main.h"
#include "GamewindowAndInput.h"
using std::cout; using std::endl;

constexpr int EVERY_NTH = 2;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::atexit(atexit_handler);
    SetConsoleCtrlHandler(cntrlHandler, TRUE);
    //create thread of &inputLoop

    global::hwnd = GWAI::getHWND();

    long i = 0;
    while (!global::exit) {
        if (global::hwnd != GetForegroundWindow()) {
            global::run = false;
            Sleep(10);
            continue;
        }
        if (GetKeyState(VK_NUMPAD3) & 0x8000/*Check if high-order bit is set (1 << 15)*/) {
            global::run = true;
            Sleep(500);
        }
        if (global::run) {
            while (global::hwnd == GetForegroundWindow()) {
                if (GetKeyState(VK_NUMPAD3) & 0x8000/*Check if high-order bit is set (1 << 15)*/) {
                    global::run = false;
                    Sleep(500);
                    break;
                }

                //insert actual main function here
                    
                if (global::exit)
                    goto begone;
            }
        }
    }
    begone:
    atexit_handler();
    return 0;
}

void atexit_handler(){
    //join threads
}
BOOL WINAPI cntrlHandler(DWORD type) {
    if (type == CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT) {
        atexit_handler();
        return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: In my experience, the main problem with allowing threads to just keep executing until the OS kills them is that the threads might access some process-wide resource (such as a global or static data structure) after the main thread has already partially or completely freed that resource; the symptom is the process occasionally crashing on exit (in a seemingly random and hard-to-reproduce way).  It also makes it difficult to check for memory leaks; if threads are still running at exit, leak-detectors will (correctly) report that resources were leaked.

Comment: Therefore in my programs I always have the main thread tell the other threads it spawned (via whatever mechanism) that it is now time for them to exit, and then call `join()` on each those threads to wait until they have exited, before cleaning up and exiting itself.  That yields a "clean", controlled, predictable shutdown sequence.

Comment: Killing threads is usually a bad thing, so are busy loops and sleeps. At shutdown you should send a signal to a thread so it can break its loop and return. Then in main wait for the threads to finish (std::thread::join or std::future.wait). Have a look at std::mutex/std::unique_lock/std::condition_variable combination to replace your sleeps and while(true). With std::condition_variable::wait.

Comment: Right, I get that synchronization measures are essential for avoiding data races, but I don't understand why a data race matters if the program is about to close anyway. If a thing crashes on exit then it has closed one way or another, so why is it a bad thing? Especially on a process where performance matters and that one extra check to see if the main thread has ordered a shutdown in every iteration of a loop might make a noticeable difference in speed to the user?

Comment: I plan to have a predetermined finite amount of threads, and none should close before the overall program closes, so shouldn't that mean there won't be any memory leaks? It is my understanding that a memory leak occurs when a program doesn't free up memory that is no longer required, but I'm fairly sure that for my program everything on the heap is going to be required right up until the program as a whole closes.

Comment: `Fairly sure` is just not good enough with multithreading. You really must design for all life cycles including shutdown. Also note that like in your case you sometimes add thread to improve responsiveness of a system (threads are not only used to speed things up). The check with condition variable is very efficient (much more so then a bussy loop), when you suspect it is a performance issue you should measure (but chances are big your bottleneck will be somewhere else).

Answer (score 0):

When working with threads nice shutdown is as important as nice startup and synchronization to avoid dataraces.

Here is an example of what I wrote in code. Online demo here https://onlinegdb.com/6IkjrQWZN:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <string>
#include <thread>

using namespace std::chrono_literals; // so we can use notations like 10ms, or 1s

class gwai_t final
{
public:
    gwai_t() = default;

    ~gwai_t()
    {
        stop();
        m_thread.join(); 
    }

    void start()
    {
        // use lambda expression : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda
        // to start the thread
        m_thread = std::thread{ [&] { loop(); } };

        // wait for the background thread to have started
        wait_for_state(state_v::running);
    }

    void stop()
    {
        // scopes matter this is one to control the lifetime of the lock
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{ m_mtx };
            if (m_state != state_v::running) return;
            m_state = state_v::stopping;
            m_condition_variable.notify_all();
        }

        wait_for_state(state_v::stopped);
    }


private:
    // A class with threads should have a state
    // to communicate and synchronize with other threads
    enum class state_v
    {
        idle,
        running,
        stopping,
        stopped
    };

    void set_state(const state_v state)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{ m_mtx };
        m_state = state;
        m_condition_variable.notify_all();
    }

    void wait_for_state(const state_v state)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{ m_mtx };

        m_condition_variable.wait(lock, [&] { return m_state == state; });
    }

    void loop()
    {
        set_state(state_v::running);
        std::cout << "loop started\n";

        while (true)
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{ m_mtx };

            // wait for loop time or change to stopping state
            // condition variable wait will not consume CPU cycles
            // for now delay is 1 second (this would have been one of your sleeps)
            auto wait_result = m_condition_variable.wait_for(lock, 1s, [&] { return m_state == state_v::stopping; });

            // if stopping then break the loop
            if (wait_result) break;

            // do your loop stuff here
            std::cout << ".";
        }

        set_state(state_v::stopped);
        std::cout << "\nloop stopped\n";
    }

    std::mutex m_mtx;
    std::condition_variable m_condition_variable; // despite its name condition variable is more of a signal
    state_v m_state{ state_v::idle };
    std::thread m_thread;
};

int main()
{
    gwai_t gwai;

    std::cout << "main start\n";
    std::cout << "press enter to end loop\n";

    gwai.start(); // start loop
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(5s); // simulate maintrhead doing all kind of things
    gwai.stop(); // and let gwai cooperatively stop background thread and synchronize with that stopping.
    
    std::cout << "main exit\n";
}
```

Comment: Right, I get that synchronization measures are essential for avoiding data races, but I don't understand why a data race matters if the program is about to close anyway. If a thing crashes on exit then it has closed one way or another, so why is it a bad thing?

Comment: It is a generic design principle, you should allow for ALL resources on a thread to be removed gracefully. Your thread may use classes which cleanup things in their destructors (eg. close files, or shutdown hardware). So all in all your task is to keep in full control during shutdown instead of hoping the OS will cleanup everything after you made a mess (it really matters when controlling hardware not managed by the OS, e.g. stopping motors on your robot).